# jQuery UI Tabs or .load() - tab links in different container than tab content and append URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I have the following html strucuture

```
<div id-"top">
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab-content-1">tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-content-2">tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-content-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--/top--></div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="tab-content-1">content 1</div>
    <div id="tab-content-2">content 2</div>
    <div id="tab-content-3">content 3</div>
<!--/bottom--></div>
```

From what I can see and in other uses, jQuery UI tabs requires the ul and the content to be in the same container, which mine aren't.

So I went with the .load() function - I changed the link's from "#tab-content-1" to "AjaxPages/tab-content-1.html" respectively for this method, and have the following code that works, but I can't get it to append the url so it would reflect the visible content so they are bookmarkable and able to be linked to directly.

```
$(function() {
      $('#content').load('AjaxPages/tab-content-1.html');
      });

        $("#tabs li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#content").load(href);
    });
```

I can add the div id to the url with basic jQuery UI tabs with this:

```
if($(".tab-set") && document.location.hash){
                $.scrollTo(".tab-set");
            }
            $(".tab-set ul").localScroll({ 
                duration:300,
                    hash:true
            });
```

with the localScroll and scrollTo plugins. Any advice? this shouldn't be this hard!

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VcQKr/2/) but can't test it entirely because you can't handle hashes from the address bar, at least clicking a link works as expected, hope it helps.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li><a href="#1">tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/top-->

<div id="content"></div><!--/bottom-->
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    function loadContentTroughHash(hash) {
        var orighash = hash ? hash : window.location.hash;
        var h =
            orighash.length > 1
            && orighash.indexOf('#') != -1
            && !isNaN(orighash.substring(1))
            ? orighash.substring(1)
            : 1;
        // hash is not just '#' but has '#' and hashtag is a number
        // else use 1
        $('#content').load('AjaxPages/tab-content-'+h+'.html');
    }

    $("#tabs li a").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $t = $(this),
            $parent = $t.parent(),
            href = $t.attr('href');
        $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        loadContentTroughHash(href);
    });

    loadContentTroughHash();

});
```